Does Voyager send its data on a schedule and hope somebody's listening?
Or is it always listening and waits for a request?
In any case, does it wait for an ack/nak to retransmit?

The current distance to Voyager 1 is ~84,100 light-seconds. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&EPHEM_TYPE=V&VEC_TABLE=6&OBJ_DATA=NO&COMMAND=-31&CENTER=%40399&TLIST=%272025-Sep-26+0%3A00%27 Voyager 2 is ~70,177 light-seconds

At the Voyagers' current distances from Earth, an ack/nak would take over 3 days (round trip time at the speed of light). So there is no ack/nak.

At the moment, the Voyagers send most of their data immediately: it's not stored on board, each measurement is sent out as it's made. They do this 24/7. For this data there's no waiting for acknowledgement or retransmission.
We don't listen all the time: on average, we listen to each Voyager for about 8 hours per day.
There is one exception: the Plasma Wave Subsystem on Voyager 1 stores its data on the on-board tape recorder. This data is played back on command from Earth. This happens on average every 6 months.

So "2 days of terror" hoping for a response to the command. :)

@Barmar waiting 2+ days for a response - reminds me of mail.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Interestingly, at the beginning of its voyage, snail mail was common on Earth, so Voyager responses were considered speedy. Now it's the opposite.

If most of the transmissions were inhibited during times nothing was expected to be listening, would there be anyplace useful for Voyager to store extra energy from the RTG?

No. The Voyagers don't carry batteries, AFAIK.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Only two days? Where I live, it takes about a week for snail mail sent from next door to reach my house. All outgoing mail is sent to a sorting facility located over 30 miles (as the crow flies) from where I live. This alone takes a couple of days (there are multiple delays). The sorting takes several more days. It eventually is sent back to my local post office, where it is sorted locally (another day or so), and then finally delivered to me.
